# How to interpret the output of safecopy

Tags: partition, data-recovery, disk-image, safecopy

Just as an example, this is one typical output line.

> ...........................[12767109](+112394240){X [12792709] X}[12818309](+209715200)

I have gone through the DESCRIPTION OF OUTPUT in [safecopy's manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/safecopy.1.html) but I still am not quite sure what exactly it means.

For example, if `(+112394240)` is "the number of blocks (or bytes) [which is it?] continuously read successfully up to this point."  and if `(+209715200)` is the "number of blocks (or bytes) of recent continuous unreadable data.", then how can the latter be larger than the former?

Additionally, what is the meaning of `{X [12792709] X}`, does it mean that only one block (block 12792709) was unreadable?

Any clarification would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Q#1:** Interpreting output

The output seems fairly straightforward. It isn't blocks (or bytes) but rather current block **and** bytes.

```
   .      Between 1 and 1024 blocks successfully read.

[xx](+yy){
          Current block and number of bytes continuously read successfully 
          up to this point.

   X      Read  failed  on a block with minimum blocksize and is skipped.  
          Unrecoverable error, destination file is padded with zeros.  Data 
          is now skipped until end of the unreadable area is reached.

   <      Successful read after the end of a bad area causes backtracking 
          with smaller blocksizes to search for the first readable data.

   }[xx](+yy)
          current block and number of bytes of recent continuous unreadable 
          data.
```

So to breakdown your sample output:

1. `....` - these mean that between 1 and 1024 blocks were successfully read.
2. `[12767109](+112394240)` - this is the number of blocks and bytes that were continuously read up to this point. The blocks are in the square brackets `[12767109]` the total bytes is in the parens, `(+112394240)`.
3. `{X [12792709] X}` - reading failed on a block, 12792709, so the data that was unreadable is padded in the destination with zeros.
4. `12818309](+209715200)` - block and continuous number of bytes that were unreadable up to this point.

> **Q#2:**  what is the meaning of {X [12792709] X}, does it mean that only one block (block 12792709) was unreadable?

That would be my interpretation of the output and the man page.

#### References

- [Statistical analysis of damaged data storage media read timings](http://safecopy.sourceforge.net/analysis/analysis.html)
- [safecopy main site](http://safecopy.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: So, does the byte size (+112394240) include the blocks that were skipped ahead in case they were unsuccessfully read, or does it only include successfully read ones?

Comment: @IsopycnalOscillation - I believe so. It's the number of bytes successfully read up until bytes in block 12792709 failed. From that point, until block `[12818309]` were unreadable. The number of bytes that were unreadable were `(+209715200)`, within that same span.